# Vertebra identification

Tags: species-identification, bone

[image][image][image]What type of vertebra is this? It was found on a beach in Corea, Maine.

Comment: Definitely mammalian and quite large; my very much a guess is seal. Any chance you could post a photo looking straight down from above with the vertebra in the orientation you have in your second photo

Comment: Thanks, I added suggested picture.